# Python return ignores multiple arguments

Tags: python, function, return

I created a function which returns two values but whenever I execute it, I get only the first value back. What can it be wrong???

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

def lasso_weighted(X,s,lam):
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    alpha = lam*2*np.sqrt(n_samples)

    g = lambda w: np.sqrt(np.abs(w))
    gprime = lambda w: 1. / (2. * np.sqrt(np.abs(w)) + np.finfo(float).eps)
    p_obj = lambda w: 1. / (2 * n_samples) * np.sum((s - np.dot(X, w)) ** 2) \
                    + alpha * np.sum(g(w))

    weights = np.ones(n_features)
   # n_lasso_iterations = 5
    counter=1
    frpr=0
    objpr=10**6
    t=10**-2

    #for k in range(n_lasso_iterations):
    while True:
        print counter
        X_w = X / weights[np.newaxis, :]
        clf = Lasso(alpha=alpha, fit_intercept=False)
        clf.fit(X_w, s)
        fr = clf.coef_ / weights
        weights = gprime(fr)
        print p_obj(fr)  # should go down
 #       if max(abs(fr-frpr))<t:
        if objpr<p_obj(fr):
            break           
        counter=counter+1
        frpr=fr
        objpr=p_obj(fr)

    return objpr,frpr
```

So if i call on my program

```
import lassoweight as ls
a,b=ls.lasso_weighted(X,S,v)
```

I only receive an error too many values to unpack. And if I run `ls.lasso_weighted(X,S,v)` then as output, I only get the first argument of return. If I change the order at the return, I take the other, but I can never take them both....)

Is this something totally stupid that I can not see?
Thanks

Comment: If you print out `objpr` and `frpr` just before the `return`, what do you get? What value exactly is returned from `lasso_weighted()` ?

Comment: I get the correct values eg objpr is a vale arounr 91.100 and fr a table [66,1]

Comment: And the value returned from lasso_weighted is the correct value of the first argument

Comment: Just return a tuple containing the two values and then assign them if you need to or continue with the tuple...

Comment: Yes this could be a solution i will try it, but why can this happening?

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Comment: Is this the whole file?  Is there a blank line at the end of the file?  If not, try adding one and running it again.

Comment: BlackCat yes there is one blank line. User there is no error instead when i run the command instead of receiving back the 2 values of the variables i just take the first one

Comment: Can somebody try it with X a mxn matrix s a nx1 matrix and v a small random variable (e.g 0.012)

Answer (score 1):

Well today I opened Canopy again (i had done also yesterday the same thing) it runs correctly returning 2 variables.... probable it was s bug or it was stuck I do not know what happened...